# I want to retrive old value, not new, from textbox in RadGrid using Javascript

Tags: javascript, telerik-grid

I have textbox(txtCustomerID) in RadGrid  with value "suraj". When i click on checkbox then is enable and that time I am edit this with "pawan" but again I am click on checkbox that time I want retrive my old value like "suraj" not "pawan".

Below is my checkbox change function:

```
 function rdoNewCustomer_OnClientCheckedChanged(sender, args) {

        var checked = sender.get_checked();
        var grid = $find("<%=rgvMultiContractAccept.ClientID %>");
        var masterTableView = grid.get_masterTableView();
        var index = sender.get_commandArgument();
        var row = masterTableView.get_dataItems()[index];

        if (checked == true) {

            row.findControl("txtCustomerID").enable(true);
            row.findControl("rdoAnotherJob").set_checked(false);


        }
        else {


            row.findControl("txtCustomerID").disable(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `data-*` attributes to store the original value of the textbox.

When the textbox is enabled you store the old value to the `data-value` attribute and when it is disabled you can retrieve the old value from the attribute and reset it to the textbox.

Here is the updated function:

```
function rdoNewCustomer_OnClientCheckedChanged(sender, args) {
    checked = sender.get_checked();
    grid = $find("<%=rgvMultiContractAccept.ClientID %>");
    masterTableView = grid.get_masterTableView();
    index = sender.get_commandArgument();
    row = masterTableView.get_dataItems()[index];

    if (checked == true) {
        row.findControl("txtCustomerID").enable(true);
        findControl("rdoAnotherJob").set_checked(false);
        var jTextBox = jQuery(row.findControl("txtCustomerID"));
        // Save the original value to the data-value attribute
        jTextBox.attr('data-value', jTextBox.val());
    }
    else {
        var jTextBox = jQuery(row.findControl("txtCustomerID"));
        // Set the original value from the data-value attribute
        jTextBox.val(jTextBox.attr('data-value'));
        row.findControl("txtCustomerID").disable(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks i will try and let you know .. thanks for help